# tf.nn.dynamic_rnn + Dataset iterator

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am building an LSTM net using the Dataset API.
The input tensor (named x in code) has different shapes for the train and the val sets and the iterator is defined without specifying an output shape.

The problem is that when tf.nn.dynamic_rnn graph_op is defined the shape of x is unknown and the following error is raised:
ValueError: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape.

Using  tf.nn.dynamic_rnn without the Dataset API works as expected.
How can this error be fixed?

TF version: 1.4

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

"""
1d: Number of examples per epoch
2d: Time steps size
3d: Batch size e.g. number of independent time series
4d: Number of points that are given as input in the lstm each time step

Batch size is usually smaller in val set because we use most of data for training.
Time steps size is bigger in val set because we want to speed up inference.

"""
x_train = np.random.rand(100, 8, 12, 2).astype(np.float32)
x_val = np.random.rand(8, 100, 4, 2).astype(np.float32)


use_dataset_api = True

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    tf.reset_default_graph()

    if not use_dataset_api:

        batch_size_pl = tf.placeholder(shape=[], dtype=tf.int32)
        x_pl = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, None, 2], dtype=tf.float32)

        cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=11)
        init_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size=batch_size_pl, dtype=tf.float32)

        rnn_outputs, current_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, x_pl, initial_state=init_state,
                                                       time_major=True, dtype=tf.float32)

        sess = tf.Session()
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        # Use first example of train set
        rnn_outputs_, current_state_ = sess.run([rnn_outputs, current_state],
                                                feed_dict={batch_size_pl: 12, x_pl: x_train[0]})

        # Use first example of val set
        rnn_outputs_, current_state_ = sess.run([rnn_outputs, current_state],
                                                feed_dict={batch_size_pl: 4, x_pl: x_val[0]})

    else:
        batch_size_pl = tf.placeholder(shape=[], dtype=tf.int32)

        train_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train))
        val_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val))

        iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_set.output_types)  # , train_set.output_shapes)

        train_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(train_set)
        val_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(val_set)

        x = iterator.get_next()

        cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=11)
        init_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size=batch_size_pl, dtype=tf.float32)

        # Raises error for tensor x: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape.
        rnn_outputs, current_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, x, initial_state=init_state,
                                                       time_major=True, dtype=tf.float32)

        sess = tf.Session()
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        # Use first example of train set
        sess.run(train_init_op)
        rnn_outputs_, current_state_ = sess.run([rnn_outputs, current_state],
                                                feed_dict={batch_size_pl: 12})

        # Use first example of val set
        sess.run(val_init_op)
        rnn_outputs_, current_state_ = sess.run([rnn_outputs, current_state],
                                                feed_dict={batch_size_pl: 4})
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change the following line:

```
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_set.output_types)
```

with:

```
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_set.output_types, [None, None, 2])
```